# Get the static methods of a class

Tags: javascript, class, static, ecmascript-6

Supposing we have a class like this:

```
class Foo {
   static bar () {}
}
```

We can call the `bar` static method using `Foo.bar()`. But how can we get an array containing only the static methods of the class?

From what I see, `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Foo)` returns more than just the `"bar"` element.

How can we get only the static methods or filter out the non-static methods from `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Foo)`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Foo)` will not return instance methods. It *will* return other properties on the class `Function` though (length, name, prototype, etc) so you can write a function to filter these out:

```
class Foo{
    static one() {}
    two() {}
    three() {}
    static four() {}
}
const all = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Foo)
    .filter(prop => typeof Foo[prop] === "function");
console.log(all); // ["one", "four"]
```

*Note:* This doesn't display any *inherited* static methods. It gets a little more messy as you'd need to do that on each function up the chain.

Comment: Getting the parent static methods should be easy since we can access the parent classes. :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: True, but you have to remember that the parent functions will be `Function` and `Object` and not necessarily classes that you've defined.

Comment: `length`, `name` and `prototype` are *not* inherited, they are own properties of the constructor function.

Comment: @Bergi Good point, updated answer. Not from the constructor though but the class Function itself